# need for 1000 dpi non PDF image from powerpoint

Tags: mac, ms-office, resolution

The journal does not want pdf nor 300dpi. They want 1000 dpi. How do I get there from mac powerpoint?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Comment: @Dominique Just to clarify, you have an image in Powerpoint (and nowhere else) that you want to extract and it has to be at least 1000dpi?

Answer (score 2):

Journals ask for esoteric and often silly image requirements all the time*. Unfortunately you're starting with an image in PowerPoint. It isn't a graphics program though, it's a slide deck program and your options are limited. This time, you will need to export as a vector (PDF), open in Preview, and then export as the DPI desired by the journal.

Start here for help: [Changing the target DPI when saving slides as images in PowerPoint 2011](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176740/changing-the-target-dpi-when-saving-slides-as-images-in-powerpoint-2011)

Note that if your image is just that - an image, NOT a chart or graph or text, but literally a photo - exporting at higher DPI will just give you a blurrily-enlarged version of your current image, NOT a crisp, clear, high-resolution file. In that case, you'd need to re-create your image at a higher resolution starting from the original source files, which (if they are not at or above 1000 dpi) might literally be not possible.

...and next time, use a proper graphics program to create your images. If cost is an issue, open source ones exist, such as Inkscape or GIMP, that will get you closer to what a journal wants when it comes time to publish. The MS Office suite is ubiquitous but that doesn't mean it's the proper tool for the job.

(*The journal requirement is silly, really, because PDF is a vector format - which means it's resolution-independent, and looks good at any size. Most journals prefer vector images. Some refuse them, for no good reason. The ONLY time a vector isn't superior is where the original artwork is something other than lines and curves, such as photographs/photomicrographs. For graphs and charts, vector is much superior.)